# How to restrict termination of k8s clusters within a project

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-iam

How to restrict termination of k8s clusters within a project, to certain users:

1. dev team creates project-dev k8s cluster
2. qa team creates project-qa k8s cluster
3. prod team creates project-prod k8s cluster

How can we prevent dev, qa, prod team members from deleting clusters which they didn't create.

How should we set up RBAC for a Google Cloud project?

Comment: So far @guillaume has posted the best answer. Use separation of privilege using different projects under an ORG. Google has recently added `IAM Conditions`. I have not reviewed the support for Kubernetes (Compute Engine Nodes) yet so this is just a suggestion for further research: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a project for each team and they create the cluster in their project. If you don't grant the teams in other projects, they won't be able to touch them.